# How to create anchor by session.createAnchor

Tags: java, augmented-reality, detect, arcore

I modify sample HelloAR project.
Add the following source code to function OnDrawFrame()

```
 public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
 ...
  Camera camera = frame.getCamera();
  //test code
  if(show) {
    show = false;
    Pose p = camera.getPose(); //Get camera pose
    Pose locpose = Pose.makeTranslation(0.0f, 0.0f, -2.0f);//define a translation
    targetpose = p.compose(locpose); //make a new pose based on camera pose
    ④anchors.add(session.createAnchor(targetpose)); //add a new anchor
  }

  // Handle taps. Handling only one tap per frame, as taps are usually low frequency
  // compared to frame rate.
...
}
```

There is an exception occur when ④ is executed, i think that pose is not correct.
My target is as below,
Create a new anchor, about anchor's postion, i hope that it is screen center in point of view of phone and the distance between camera and anchor is 2 meter in point of 3D world.

How to define that pose?

Comment: What does "in the distance" mean here? At which range does it cease to work for you?

Comment: How far is "far"? How many meters? Or how large in pixels is the image of the plane in camera resolution when you try to detect it? It is still very unclear what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Gábor Bakos I edit my question with source code. please check again.

Comment: I found the root cause: Test code is executed too earlier, when some pointcloud is create, then execute test code, a new anchor is created. i will close the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the root cause: Test code is executed too earlier, when some pointcloud is create, then execute test code, a new anchor is created. i will close the issue